# wsdl file not deployed in jboss eap 7

Tags: jboss, wsdl, migration

I have been trying to migrating from jboss eap 5.1 to jboss eap 7. My .war file has been deployed successfully but not my .wsdl file. I have used jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the below code:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
            <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
            <exclude-subsystems>  
                <subsystem name="webservices" />  
            </exclude-subsystems>  
        <exclusions>
                <module name="javaee.api" />
                    <module name="javax.ws"/>
            </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
                <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true"/>   
            </dependencies> 
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Is there anything I have missed out?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?